# TextField label border position

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making a form with several text fields. I need to have a label above each field displayed.I don't want to have to click in the field to show the text above each field. They need to be fixed.

Using label text, the label only shows when the user clicks in the field, I need that to be fixed.

I tried:

```dart
static TextField user_name() {
            return TextField(
                maxLines: 2,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Full Name',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),          
                ));
}
```

But only shows 'Full Name' when the user clicks on the field.

Comment: From the labelText description if only show on top when TextField is on focus and non-empty, link: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/labelText.html
Or maybe use Text and Column to do it instead since they are fixed?

Comment: If I use Text and Column, how I could have the decorated border around a Text exactly as the textfield does? If that's an easy question, sorry to ask, is my first week using Dart and flutter.

Comment: you could use both labelText: and hintText:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am also new to flutter. I just suggest another approach may  possible do that.

I used a Stack to allow the label(Text) to cover the TextField. 
But there is a problem after as the Text color will not change after I focus the TextField. Then I use the FocusNode to listen the focus change and call setState to update.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  FocusNode _focusNode = new FocusNode();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //Add Listener to know when is updated focus
    _focusNode.addListener(_onLoginUserNameFocusChange);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    //Dispose Listener to know when is updated focus
    _focusNode.addListener(_onLoginUserNameFocusChange);
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _onLoginUserNameFocusChange() {
    //Force updated once if focus changed
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[

            //original one, just to check the style
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 5, 5, 5),
                child: TextField(
                    maxLines: 2,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Full Name',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    ))),

            //The 5,5,5,5 padding just for easier look, you can start from the Stack
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 5, 5, 5),
                child: Stack( //try to allow drawing label Text over the container
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      // this padding is to allow the Text draw on the top of the border
                      //since default font size is 12, half of it
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 6, 0, 0),
                        child: TextField(// the main TextField
                          maxLines: 2,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          ),
                          //This is used to listen the focus of this TextField
                          focusNode: _focusNode,
                        )),
                    Container(
                      //position label
                      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(7, 0, 0, 0),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(4, 0, 4, 0), // input outline default seems using 4.0 as padding from their source
                      child: Text(
                        'Full Name',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 12,
                          color: _focusNode.hasFocus ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                        ),
                      ),
                      color: Colors.white, //just to cover the intercepted border 
                    )
                  ],
                )),
          ]),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: CbL, your approach works well with several components?Like 24 textfields?I am out of my Desktop right now, I will test your solution tomorrow and report.

Comment: If there is no other complicated widget on that page, I think 24 TextFields with scrollview performance is okay on my android 5.0 phone. But for better performance, if the page is really simple that all textfields and labels are placed quite regular on UI design, I will suggest use a ListView to hold them to reduce the actual redrawed widget.

Comment: CbL, your solution worked fine. In my work, I prefered to use a label with a horizontal divider to simulate a form in each textfield.I will keep your solution in mind to another work.Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 22):

You could use a `TextFormField` like so:

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    floatingLabelBehavior:FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
 static TextField user_name(){
    return TextField(
        maxLines: 2,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
        // lableText:"Full name",
          hintText:'Full name',

          border: OutlineInputBorder(),

        ));
  }
```

You can get your answer through hinttext.