# How to set position label text in TextFormField in outlineborder?

Tags: flutter, flutter-textformfield

How to set position label in TextFormField in outlineborder?

i want set text position. Because, label prefer to bottom not center in border

[image: TextFormField]

Comment: fix after add Height: 1 in TextStyle

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation for the label

> Text that describes the input field.
>
> When the input field is empty and unfocused, the label is displayed on
> top of the input field (i.e., at the same location on the screen where
> text may be entered in the input field). When the input field receives
> focus (or if the field is non-empty), the label moves above (i.e.,
> vertically adjacent to) the input field.

So, basically this is the behavior for the label. If you want something else you have to make it on your own ( using a Stack widget with a TextField and a Text ). But with this solution you have to treat the focus properties as well on your own.
You can use this post as a reference

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58039585/10143503